# ¿Cómo redireccionar paquetes desde https (443) a http(80) para el Portal Cautivo en RouterOS Mikrotik?

Tags: html

La idea es que cuando el usuario ingrese a la red inalámbrica y este necesita autenticarse en el hotspot atraves de un portal cautivo; el sistema Hotspot de Mikrotik sea capaz de redirigirle desde https a http para que pueda autentificarse sin problemas. Por ejemplo; si el usuario trata de ingresar a https://algundominio.com, el sistema redirijará a http://hotspot.local o la IP del servidor hostpot.

Como ejemplo que no me funciona es esto:

```
/ip firewall nat add 
action=redirect 
chain=hotspot 
comment=Redireccionar dst- 
port=443 hotspot=local-dst 
protocol=tcp to-ports=80
```

Answer (score 2):

No es posible realizar dicha redireccion. Para poder aceptar `https`, debes primero tener un certificado valido y cargado en el equipo, desde `/system certificates`, luego en el hotspot debes activar la opcion de `https` en `/ip hotspot server-profile` pestaña `Login`, tildar la opcion `https` y seleccionar el certificado SSL.